# Techniques to Get rid of low level Locking

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, locking

I'm wondering, and in need, of strategies that can be applied to reducing low-level locking.
However the catch here is that this is not new code (with tens of thousands of lines of C++ code) for a server application, so I can't just rewrite the whole thing.

I fear there might not be a solution to this problem by now (too late). However I'd like to hear about good patterns others have used.

Right now there are too many lock and not as many conflicts, so it's a paranoia induced hardware performance issue.
The best way to describe the code is as single threaded code suddenly getting peppered with locks.

Comment: Is the problem CPU spent wastefully acquiring and releasing locks or is the problem excessive contention for some locks?

Comment: low-level? As in coarse grained ?

Comment: is this a desktop application or a web solution? why are there all these locks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to eliminate the low-level locking? Do you have deadlock issues? Do you have performance problems? Or scaling issues? Are the locks generally contended or uncontended?

What environment are you using? The answers in C++ will be different to the ones in Java, for example. E.g. uncontended synchronization blocks in Java 6 are actually relatively cheap in performance terms, so simply upgrading your JRE might get you past whatever problem you are trying to solve. There might be similar performance boosts available in C++ by switching to a different compiler or locking library.

In general, there are several strategies that allow you to reduce the number of mutexes you acquire.

First, anything only ever accessed from a single thread doesn't need a mutex.

Second, anything immutable is safe provided it is 'safely published' (i.e. created in such a way that a partially constructed object is never visible to another thread).

Third, most platforms now support atomic writes - which can help when a single primitive type (including a pointer) is all that needs protecting. These work very similarly to optimistic locking in a database. You can also use atomic writes to create lock-free algorithms to replace more complex types, including Map implementations. However, unless you are very, very good, you are much better off borrowing somebody else's debugged implementation (the java.util.concurrent package contains lots of good examples) - it is notoriously easy to accidentally introduce bugs when writing your own algorithms.

Fourth, widening the scope of the mutex can help - either simply holding open a mutex for longer, rather than constantly locking and unlocking it, or taking a lock on a 'larger' item - the object rather than one of its properties, for example. However, this has to be done extremely carefully; you can easily introduce problems this way.

Answer (score 1):

The threading model of your program has to be decided before a single line is written. Any module, if inconsistent with the rest of the program, can crash, corrupt of deadlock the application.

If you have the luxury of starting fresh, try to identify large functions of your program that can be done in parallel and use a thread pool to schedule the tasks. The trick to efficiency is to avoid mutexes wherever possible and (re)code your app to avoid contention for resources at a high level.

Answer (score 0):

You may find some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92455/how-can-i-write-a-lock-free-structure) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120937/what-is-test-and-set-used-for#120976) helpful as you look for ways to atomically update shared state without explicit locks.