# In C++, is it possible to access a static variable in the constructor?

Tags: c++, static, constructor

I am trying:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass();

    int myID;
    static int currentID;
};

MyClass::MyClass() {
    myID = currentID;
    ++currentID;
}
```

I'm trying to assign a unique ID to all the instances of this class.

Edit:

It doesn't work for me. I get two of these in xcode:

Undefined symbols:
  "GameObject::currentID", referenced from:
      __ZN10GameObject9currentIDE$non_lazy_ptr in GameObject.o
     (maybe you meant: __ZN10GameObject9currentIDE$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Ideally, you would look at the singleton that uses boost::once to see how race-free initialization of statics works. You should also use tbb::atomic<T> / std::atomic<T> to prevent race conditions. Those two modifications complete, your code is now thread-safe.

Comment: Run-time-wise, yes. Compile-time-wise, you need to (re-)define `int MyClass::currentID` outside of class scope.

Comment: @moshbear: technically he needs to *define* what he has provided is a *declaration* (i.e. the `re-` in *(re-)define* should not be there)

Comment: Be careful if you plan to use MyClass in STL containers. The code may not behave the same as you expected.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Hence the parentheses to indicate uncertainty. I tend to forget the distinction between declaration and definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It works for me:**

```
#include <iostream>

class My
{
    public:
    My() : id(++currentId) {}

    int id;
    static int currentId;
};

int My::currentId = 0;

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, My & m)
{
    return os << m.id;
}

int main()
{
    My a;
    My b;
    My c;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
> ./x
1
2
3
```

Comment: Didn't have the initializer like vrbilgi mentions. You  were the first to write it. Why does there need to be an int in front, why not just: My::currentId = 0;

Comment: @Ryan: That is not *initialization* (or rather not *only* initialization), but rather the actual *definition* of the static member: `int My::currentId/* = 0*/;` *defines* the variable (reserves the space for the variable), removing the comment it also *initializes*, but the important bit is that this is the *definition*

Comment: @stefanB: The last comment makes no sense: the variable is not `const`

Comment: it is the syntax of initialising static class variables

Answer (score 3):

Besides the others' cases, it works in the following cases:

```
MyClass a[10];
MyClass* b = new MyClass[10];
```

Be careful if you use STL containers to hold `MyClass` objects. **It may not behave the same as you expected, and the problem is hard to find.** See the following example:

```
int MyClass::currentID = 0;
...
std::vector<MyClass> c(10);
MyClass a;
```

In this case, The result is the following:

```
c[0].myID = 0;
c[1].myID = 0;
....
c[9].myID = 0
=============
   a.myID = 1.
```

**The default constructor is executed only ONE time. The reason is that the constructor of std::vector will use the same value to initial all the element of the vector.** In my system, the constructor of std::vector is the following:

```
  explicit
  vector(size_type __n, const value_type& __value = value_type(),
     const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
  : _Base(__n, __a)
  { _M_fill_initialize(__n, __value); }
```

`_M_fill_initialize` will initialize the memory allocated using `__value` (which comes from default constructor `value_type()`) `__n` times.

The code above will eventually call `uninitialized_fill_n`, which does the following:

```
for (; __n > 0; --__n, ++__cur)
    std::_Construct(&*__cur, __x);
```

Here is `std::_Contruct`:

```
template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
inline void
_Construct(_T1* __p, const _T2& __value)
{
  // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
  // 402. wrong new expression in [some_]allocator::construct
  ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(__value);
}
```

Here you can see it finally calls global operator `new` to initialize each element in the vector using the **same** value.

The conclusion is, **using static member to initial data member will work in most of the cases, but it may fail if you plan to use it in STL containers, and the problem is hard to find.** I only tried `std::vector`, it is quite possible that the problem exists when using other kind of stl containers with `MyClass` objects.

Comment: The constructor for `vector` in c++98 is in fact as you said, and the default constructor is only called to form the default argument. But in C++0x, the specification split this constructor in two: `explicit vector(size_type n);` and `vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());`. for the first one, the specification says the vector should `Constructs a vector with n value-initialized elements.`, which requires the default constructors to be called `n` times. Anyway, the approach of the OP should be used with caution in this situation.

Comment: I am using MyClass with stl containers, but I am only using stl containers to hold pointers to MyClass. For example: myVector.push_back(new MyClass()); Is it okay to use like that?

Comment: @Ryan It is OK then, just make sure that each time the default constructor is called and you know what exactly happening under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

```
int MyClass::currentID=0;
```

If not done you need to do this in CPP file

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error is not because you're accessing the static from the constructor, which is legal btw, but because you're not defining it.

```
class My
{
    public:
    My() : id(++currentId) {}

    int id;
    static int currentId;
};

//place the definition in the implementation file
int My::currentId = 0;
```

Comment: @stefanB: If you are suggesting that he copied, I would not think so, there are not that many things that can be done so he can have got to the same code *without* copying, and besides, contrary to your version, he actually *explains* in the code with the comment what the line does: *defininion of the variable*. +1 for the answer that actually *mentions* that the missing part is the definition

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you define and initialize static member of the class outside the class. This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
class MyClass {
private:
    int myID;
    static int currentID;
public:
   //default constructor
    MyClass()
        : myID(currentID) 
        {
            ++currentID;
        }

    void printId() { std::cout << "Object Id :" << myID << std::endl; } /*Prints the unique ID assigned to each object.*/
};

// define the static class member here:
int MyClass::currentID = 1;

int main()
{
    MyClass m1, m2, m3;
    m1.printId();
    m2.printId();
    m3.printId();
}
```

Output:

Object Id :1

Object Id :2

Object Id :3

Answer (score 0):

yes that is fine, provided you have no static instances of MyClass.

Comment: @Ryan that's a different issue. you will need to *define* the static variable in the cpp file -- as vrbilgi, StefanB, and Luchian have now demonstrated for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's ok. But the code as you wrote it is not thread-safe: 2 classes can be instantiated simultaneously in different threads. The 2nd instance could grab the same value of `currentID` before the first instance had time to increment the static variable.

This may or may not be an issue for you.

If you need thread-safety, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93073) should help.